# Why QIcon / QPixmap loaded image format should be png (and not svg) to be displayed in binary?

Tags: qt, svg, binary, cmake, qt5

I have a Qt application where I load and display icons. This is a self-contained example of how I do it. In `main.cpp` I have:

```
Q_INIT_RESOURCE(Icons);
QApplication qapp(argc, argv);
QMainWindow window;
QAction* action = new QAction(QIcon(":/icon.png"), QObject::tr("&Icon"), &window);
QToolBar* tb = window.addToolBar(QObject::tr("Test"));
tb->addAction(action);

window.show();
return qapp.exec();
```

With `Icons.qrc` being the resource file.

My `CMakeLists.txt` contains:

```
# ...
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui OpenGL)
set(SOURCES main.cpp)
qt5_add_resources(ICON_RSC Data/Icons.qrc)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${ICON_RSC})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::OpenGL)
```

Assume I create a binary of my application: I copy generated `exe` file and all the necessary Qt, platform and plugin `dll`s where they are supposed to be in application folder. My binary application runs with no problem if I use `icon.png`.

However, I want to use `svg` format. If I replace `icon.png` to `icon.svg`, the application compiles and runs from source, but the binary does not show the icon anymore.

My question is why does it happen? Is it something to do with missing library in my binary folder (I included `imageformats` folder and I can see `qsvg.dll` there, I also included `iconengines` folder with `qsvgicon.dll` inside); or Qt was designed not to use `svg` files for icons?

I tested the application on Qt5.4, Qt5.5 on Windows 7 and 10. Qt kits are MSVC2010 and MSVC2013 - 32bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should link to `Qt5::SVG` and include the Qt XML library, cfr. [here](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Library_Cross_Dependencies#PlugIns).

You can probably add both to your CMake file:

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui OpenGL SVG XML)
```

and

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::OpenGL Qt5::SVG Qt5::XML)
```

Comment: @vicru someone else already did it for me. It should work now.

Comment: Thank you so much! I added the packages in my CMake file as you suggested, and in order for my binary application to run, I had to copy to the binary folder the corresponding `dll`s: `Qt5Xml.dll` and `Qt5Svg.dll`.